# How to detect the "real" last table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to round the corners of the first and last tableView cells, but I'm having a problem. When scrolling, my last reusable tableView cell returns the wrong indexPath.row. So it goes from 0 to 9, since I have an array with 10 items, then 6 to 9 then 3 to 4. From my research I concluded this is happening because the cells are being reused, but it only happens when scrolling. When tapping on a cell it returns the correct indexPath.row as expected.

I've tried some solutions such as:

- Explicitly returning the amount of cells (which is 10).
- Explicitly checking for the section as well, but it's unnecessary since I always have only one section.
- Detecting the last cell with "indexPath.row == array.count -1" or "indexPath.row == array.count".

None of these work, especially the last one. I put a breakpoint to check on the indexPath.row when the last cell is shown and it returns "3", not 9 which is what I expect (since I have 10 cells).

Returning number of cells:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let resultsCount = results?.count else { return 0 }
    return resultsCount
}
```

Setting up cells:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let customTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    // Setup stuff
    ...

    if indexPath.row == 0 { // if first cell
        // Do something
        ...
    } else if indexPath.row == results!.count - 1 { // if last cell
        // Do something
        ...
    } else {
        // Do something
        ...
    }

    return searchResultsCell
}
```

Also tried with this instead of doing it in cellForRowAt:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

[Image for illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx3oe.png)

Is there another way to get the real indexPath.row of the last cell while scrolling so I can round its bottom corners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, as you said, that cells are reused. You are rounding  the top corners for the cell when its row is 0, but you have forgotten to *unround* the corners for the cell when its row is *not* zero. Similarly for the last row.

Comment: I was "unrounding" the corners in the else statement with the wrong function, but that's fixed now. Thanks for bringing it to my attention. So now the first cell is rounded and the rest **including** the last cell is unrounded. Do you have any ideas aside from using three separate cellReuseIdentifiers for top, center and bottom (as @vikingosegundo recommended) which might help with correctly guessing the last cell? I'd like to avoid duplicated cells with minimum changes if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use 3 differnt cell reuse identifiers for top, centre and bottom cells. now they each cell will only be used for one of those cases.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below code for improving your solution,

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {

   cell.yourView.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft,.topRight], radius: 30)

} else if indexPath.row == totalRow - 1 {

    cell.yourView.roundCorners(corners: [.bottomRight,.bottomLeft], radius: 30)

} else {

    cell.yourView.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft,.topRight,.bottomRight,.bottomLeft], radius: 0)

}


extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: My implementation already looks as your example. My only issue is that the last cell's `indexPath.row` **is NOT equal** to  `totalRow - 1` as it should be, hence the corners aren't being rounded. This change in indexPath happens only when scrolling. As also mentioned in one other comment, it happens because the cell is being reused, so it's also reusing the indexPath of that cell instead of assigning said cell the actual indexPath in the tableView.

Answer (score -2):

I redid the whole view and now it's working as expected, but unfortunatly I still don't know what was causing the issue. Maybe, unlikely, a bug in the simulator since it was working fine on a real device :/